# elocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, levenshtein-distance, shared-objects, fpic

My server is on ubuntu 12.04.

I'm trying to install the Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF available here :  https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF

I downloaded the .zip and locate the levenshtein.c file here on my server : /home/username/levenshtein.c

When I enter in my terminal the following command :

```
gcc -o levenshtein.so -shared /home/username/levenshtein.c -I /usr/include/mysql/
```

I obten this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCPQijg.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

/tmp/ccCPQijg.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I googled the error to find how to solve it and I install build-essential, but after I have the same error.

I don't know how I can use -fPIC to recompile correctly what I must recompile...

I found a lot of topics which are a little bit different of mine and I don't know what I could do now to solve my problem.

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks ;-)

BBFUNK01

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. After `build-essential` installation compile shared library with `-fPIC` flag:

```
gcc -fPIC -o levenshtein.so -shared /home/username/levenshtein.c -I /usr/include/mysql/
```

Just in case I also install `libc6-dev`.